# How should I use useQuery when I need to display two values on the screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I know that React query calls the api with useQuery to turn the data into a map and display it on the screen.

```
export const getList = async() => { 
  const response = await api.get(/~/~/~/list); 
  return response.data; 
};
```

```
export const getNewList = async() => { 
  const response = await api.get(/~/~/~/Newlist); 
  return response.data; 
};
```

If there are two things to import, how should I use useQuery on the page? I'm Korean and I'm sorry if the translation is strange, the api was specified by the backend We are making a practice project I called `useQuery` twice `const { isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery()` Called twice in this way, it turned out that block scope variables could not be declared again.

Answer (score 1):

you can write it simply like this

```
const getListQuery = useQuery(...)
const getNewListQuery = useQuery(...)
```

then you can use the variables from it

```
if (getListQuery.isLoading) {
 ...
}
...
```

Comment: Should I write isLoding and error like that for everything to be sprinkled on the screen?
for example
if (getListQuery. isLoading) {
  ...
}
...


if (getNewList. isLoading) {
...
}
...

Comment: Sure, of course you can. As now you've already had 2 objects, you can use `getListQuery. isLoading`, `getListQuery. data`, `getNewList. isLoading`, `getNewList. data`,... whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

would be great if you could provide an example code snipped in codebox, so it is easier to see exact problem. If i understand correctly, your problem is that you cannot use same variable name twice, so what you can do is destruct the response and rename it.

```
{ isLoading, isError, data } = useQuery() 
{ isLoading: isLoadingSecondQuery, isError: isErrorSecondQuery, data: dataSecondQuery } = useQuery()
```